# Where exactly do taxis pickup passengers in Las Vegas Airport (LAS)

Tags: airport-transfer, taxis, las-vegas, las

I pose this question because once I understand this, I can try to predict the taxi route: I'd like to make a stop between the airport and the hotel, but need to understand the starting point.

[image]

Comment: Unless the stop is on Airport grounds, it won't make that much difference.  The main cab stand is on the south east side of the Arrivals hall, between the terminal and parking garage.

Comment: For future reference, when asking questions about a specific airport, please use the airport's tag which is its three-letter IATA code (LAS here).

Comment: The taxi driver is going to take the route that he/she feels is best based on time of day, traffic, destination, etc.  Any route you plot will be pure speculation, irregardless of the taxi stand's location at the airport.

Comment: Let's face it, at LAS 90% of the time the taxi is going to long haul you through the tunnel unless you tell them otherwise.

Comment: @user3761894  When you say 'long haul' does this mean take you through the longest route to increase the fare?

Comment: Even if the driver takes the longest feasible route from LAS to Caesar's Palace, it can't be more than USD 1 or 2 difference. Just tell him you want to go straight up the strip.

Comment: The shortest route on the map is not the fastest, so you might actually pay more for the 'shorter' route, while you sit in traffic.

Comment: @gatorback Not longest, but a longer than necessary route.  There's a tunnel that leads to the freeway that can add $5-$10 to the fare, depending on where you're going.  It's a more expensive fare for almost every location on the Strip, with the possible exception of Mandalay Bay.  Vegas cab drivers are notorious for defaulting to taking tourists through the tunnel unless asked otherwise.

Comment: @GayotFow Straight up the Strip is going to be slower (although also more scenic for new visitors).  Going up Koval or Paradise is generally the fastest and cheapest way.  Getting tunneled probably adds ~$5 to the fare.  Going up the Strip on a busy weekend night could easily add quite a lot more.

Answer (score 3):

You can see an interactive map of the airport at https://www.mccarran.com/Fly/MyJourneyMap.aspx#.  If you click "Ground Transportation" on the left side, and then "Taxis", you will see yellow icons showing the locations of taxi pickup.  There is one taxi stand at Terminal 1 and two at Terminal 3, so you will need to check which terminal your flight arrives at.

[image]